# "I am a boy." vs. "I am boy." How native speakers feel if there is no article like "a" or "an"?

Tags: articles, zero-article

"I am a boy." vs. "I am boy." How natives speakers feel if there is no article like "a" or "an"?

Could anybody describe what kind of syntax or feeling you have when you hear a sentence without "a" or "an"?

Comment: I think "That's a foreigner whose native language doesn't have indefinite articles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an article when it is grammatically required is imperative. Without a/an it is not only grammatically incorrect, but it also sounds really bad and will label you as a beginner English student, which you clearly aren't. This is the type of mistake that makes it into discriminatory ELL stereotypes.

Thankfully, this is one of the easier things to improve on in English because it actually (almost) always follows its rule (i.e. "an" before a noun starting with a vowel, or "a" before a noun starting with a consonant).

Comment: "Stereotypes" - Missing out articles is what we expect Russians to do.

Comment: Isn't it interesting that only 'a' makes a big difference? English is crazy.

Comment: @Brandon, it certainly is, but English is far from unique in this aspect. German, Spanish, French, Italian, Portuguese, and many more all have articles like this that native speakers would find very wrong if left missing.

Comment: @Brandon - Articles are useful. There is an important difference between "I smashed an egg" and "I smashed the egg".

Comment: “I am legend” is acceptable, unlike “I am boy”. And “I, Robot”.

Comment: Dropping the article can be used poetically, however:  "I am woman, hear me roar!" is a famous example.  This is changing the noun into a more abstract, almost platonic concept instead of a concrete thing.  I would not recommend ELLs try it.